# How can I get array from child in the JavaScript firebase sdk from database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Here is my database Image.]

I want to display all the values in the vertex. How can I do this?
Currently the following code give me null value.

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref("data/aqibkhan109").child('corn').child('polygon19').child('vertex');

        dbRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
          console.log(snapshot.val());
        });
```

Any help Please, It's a realtime database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first node of your database is "Data" with a capital D, but your code is using "data" with a lowercase d.  The database is always case sensitive, and queries need to match exactly.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, it worked. I was using small data. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
ref("data/aqibkhan109")
```

into this:

```
ref("Data/aqibkhan109")
```

`data` should use capital letter same as in the database.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, it worked. I was using small data. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Data/aqibkhan109/corn/polygon19/vertex");
dbRef.on('value',snapshot=>{
console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Try this. I hope it will work for you.